# How to call a variable of the same name in if-statement

Tags: c++, scoping

How do I call a variable that has the same name as a variable instantiated inside of an if-statement? Here's some code for reference:

```
int main() {
   int x = 5;
   
   if (x) {
       int x = 2;
       cout << x << endl; // should print out 2.
       cout << ::x << endl; // should print out 5.
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I know that the second `cout` line is incorrect, so what would the correct way of writing it be?

Comment: give it a different name? There is no other way

Comment: This is not possible. You can't do this even as an academic curiosity.

Comment: Might be called a shadow variable. But as others say you cannot access the first one.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Not a down voter but question askers are expected to do some research before posting.  I found the dupe target with a single google search and picking the second link google gave me.